# simple_form_for with custom controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, simple-form-for

This line in my users index view:

```
<%= simple_form_for current_user, :url => user_change_client_path,
                                  :method => :patch,
                                  :id => current_user.id do |f| %>
```

generates the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"change_client", :controller=>"users"} missing required keys: [:user_id]
```

I have the change_client action defined in my controller. In my routes.rb I have:

```
resources :users, only: [:index] do
  patch 'change_client'
  patch 'approve'
end
```

Rake routes shows:

```
user_change_client PATCH  /users/:user_id/change_client(.:format)   users#change_client
user_approve PATCH  /users/:user_id/approve(.:format)               users#approve
```

What am I doing wrong that's causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route below:

```
user_change_client PATCH  /users/:user_id/change_client(.:format)
```

Requires a `user_id` parameter. When you call this helper, pass your current user to it like so:

```
user_change_client_path(current_user)
```

Comment: so how would I incorporate this into the simple_form_for line of code? I tried a couple variations and keep getting a syntax error

Comment: Does `<%= simple_form_for current_user, :url => user_change_client_path(current_user), :method => :patch do |f| %>` not work? That error message is specifically about the url helper method. Make sure there's not another place you're calling it by accident either.

Comment: ah was just coming back to say I accidentally deleted the "do", no syntax errors now, thanks! now testing to make sure everything works properly

Comment: params[:id] is nil in the controller action, trying to figure out why now, specifying :id => current_user.id in the simple_form_for line doesn't help

Comment: params[:user_id] works, guess I lose params[:id] shorthand when I do it this way

Comment: it's a conventions thing. params[:id] is usually for the last item in your path, like this: `users/:user_id/children/:id`